# ¿Como hacer un doble JOIN en SQL?

Tags: sql

Quiero saber cuentos tiempos un `subscriber_id` ha gustado un hashtag que estan sobre publicidades que llamamos `eclipse_id`.

Tengo dos tablas en mi base de datos :

swipe que me da si ha un subscriber gustado una publicidad :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ha gustado un subscriber una publicidad cuando `state` ={2,3,5,6,8,9}

Aqui esta la base de datos de eclipse_hastag con la correspondancia entre las publicidades y los hashtag con las que están asociadas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui esta la consulta para saber si un `subscriber_id` ha gustado un hashtag a través de una publicidad :

```
-- matrice utilisateur, hastag
SELECT COUNT (swipe.state),eclipse_hashtag.hashtag_id,swipe.subscriber_id  FROM swipe
  INNER JOIN eclipse_hashtag ON eclipse_hashtag.eclipse_id = swipe.eclipse_id
  WHERE swipe.state= 3 OR swipe.state = 6 or swipe.state=9
    GROUP BY eclipse_hashtag.hashtag_id,swipe.subscriber_id
      ORDER BY eclipse_hashtag.hashtag_id DESC;
```

Creo que la solucion fue un doble JOIN peron no soy seguro y no sé como hacerlos y la siguiente esta mi primera :

```
-- matriz usario, hashtag
SELECT COUNT(swipe.eclipse_id), subscriber_hashtag.hashtag_id,subscriber_hashtag.subscriber_id  FROM subscriber_hashtag
  -- join para que las publicidades/eclipses que gusta un usarios estan vinculadas con las de la tabla de correspondencia con los hashtag
  INNER JOIN eclipse_hashtag ON eclipse_hashtag.hashtag_id = subscriber_hashtag.hashtag_id
  -- join para que los usarios  estan vinculadas con los de la tabla de correspondencia con los hashtag
  LEFT OUTER JOIN swipe ON subscriber_hashtag.subscriber_id = swipe.subscriber_id
  -- recobremos los "me gusta"
  WHERE swipe.state= 3 OR swipe.state = 6 or swipe.state=9
    GROUP BY subscriber_hashtag.hashtag_id,subscriber_hashtag.subscriber_id
      ORDER BY subscriber_hashtag.hashtag_id DESC;
```

Aqui est el output, pero me parece un poquito elevado y no se porque no se ordena los `subscriber_id`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Si, [swipe] es la tabla donde tienes la relación entre suscriber_id y eclipse_id, [eclipse_hastag] está la relacón entre eclipse_id y hashtag_id, y lo que necesitas es cuantas veces un suscriber_id a gustado un hashtag_id tu consulta sería:

```
SELECT a.suscriber_id, b.hashtag_id, COUNT(*) as 'Tiempos'
FROM swipe as a
INNER JOIN eclipse_hastag
ON (a.eclipse_id = b.eclipse_id)
GROUP BY a.suscriber_id, b.hashtag_id
ORDER BY Tiempos DESC
```

Un concejo, puedes usar alias en tu código para mejorar la lectura.

Saludos, espero te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias, sin embargo no conozco los alias por lo momento. Consultaré esto.

Comment: Las alias te ayudan a apodar la tabla, como en el código, [swipe] as a. Con "as" le apodas un nombre a la tabla, en este caso 'a'. Para que cuando llames columnas de la tabla solo debes usar: a.[nombre de la columna] como en el ON del JOIN. Saludos.

Comment: hmm.. me dice Postgre `[2017-06-07 11:13:13] [42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "'Tiempos'"
[2017-06-07 11:13:13] Position: 50`

Comment: ah, lo siento usas postgres, no uses comillas simples para hacer definir el alias, quedaría asi: as Tiempos.